# cabal can't read bytestring cabal file, with ghc 7.4.1

Tags: haskell, ghc

I just upgraded from GHC 7.2.2 to 7.4.1 on 32-bit linux. The install went fine, but cabal-install is not happy:

```
$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
$ cabal install repa
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Couldn't read cabal file "bytestring/0.9.2.1/bytestring.cabal"
```

Here's the cabal version I'm running:

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 0.10.2
using version 1.10.1.0 of the Cabal library
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a problem with the current Hackage index - I'm getting the same problem after a cabal update on a previously working system.

Answer (score 5):

There's a workaround through here: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2012-February/099077.html

Answer (score 4):

run this after you run `cabal update`:

```
tar -f ~/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/00-index.tar --delete bytestring/0.9.2.0
tar -f ~/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/00-index.tar --delete bytestring/0.9.2.1
```

Comment: I did this and it's still not working. Does anyone knows what could be wrong?